# When using OpenSSL self-signed certificates, could knowing the input data aid in an attack against the encryption?

Tags: security, openssl

I have been creating a few certificates using OpenSSL recently and in the process of creating the certificates, the program asks me questions such as my location, details about my business and the like.

My question is whether knowledge of these details can aide an attacker in breaking my encryption and if so, is spoofing the data the optimal solution?

Comment: short answer no, those information does not aid attackers from breaking the encryption unless the data reflected back to the output (e.g BREACH). the only way your encryption is broken is with expensive operation (or sophisticated method that nobody knows yet), or using weak algorithm for the key (e.g. [SHA1](http://shattered.io/) which should be banned already), or having your [private key leaked](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/18/d_link_code_signing_key_leak/). sorry for the flag, this question better to go to [Security STE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58793/how-safe-are-encrypted-websites-really/58800#58800

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Security SE where it is already answered.